# Why am I getting a segmentation fault? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

Problem: A program to count the number of times a number repeats in an array using recursion.

What I've done: I've tried every way I know, I've gone with an output array for storing indices of the number, and just ++ to another number on finding a match to current number. Nothing seems to work, it's one error or another (I'm a noob). I tried looking for solutions online, found solutions on 3-4 websites but had no clue what was going on.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int ind(int a[], int size, int x){
    int j;
    if(size == 0){
        return 0;}
    else if (a[0]==x){
        j++;
        return j;
    }
    reind(a++,size—,x);
}
int main(){
    int a[5] = {1,2,3,3,5};
    ind(a, 5, 3);
}
```

Edit: That "reind" was a typo, I still get segmentation fault with "ind". Sorry for that.

Comment: Include the code as text in the body of your question, not as an image

Comment: `int j; j++;` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: `ind` exhibits undefined behavior by way of reaching the closing brace of a non-`void` function without encountering a `return` statement.

Comment: Heed your compiler warnings. You should have several. Don't ignore them.

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a number of mistakes in this code:

- `j` is uninitialized, and even if it weren’t, you are not using the value of `j` correctly.
- There is a missing `return` on the recursive call to `ind()` (is that what the `re` was supposed to be?).
- You are passing the *original* values of `a` and `size` to the recursive `ind()`, causing an endless loop. You are using the post-increment and post-decrement operators, which return the original values, not the new values. You would need to use the pre-increment and pre-decrement operators instead. Which is a bit overkill in this situation, as you don’t use the variables anymore after they are adjusted. So simple addition and subtraction operators can be used instead.
- `main()` is ignoring the return value of `ind()`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ind(int a[], int size, int x){
    int j = 0;
    if (size == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    if (a[0] == x){
        ++j;
    }
    return j + ind(a+1, size-1, x);
}

int main(){
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 3, 5};
    cout << ind(a, 5, 3);
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/3qkYKm)

That being said, `j` and the 2nd `if` can be eliminated completely:

```cpp
int ind(int a[], int size, int x){
    if (size == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return (a[0] == x ? 1 : 0) + ind(a+1, size-1, x);
}
```

Or:

```cpp
int ind(int a[], int size, int x){
    if (size == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    return int(a[0] == x) + ind(a+1, size-1, x);
}
```

Comment: But I initialised j in the first line.

Comment: What value, in your opinion, does `j` have after `int j;` line?

Comment: @RohitMalik no, you *declared* `j` but you did not *initialize* it with a value.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm a stupid, it would have a random value.But even after initialising it with 0, I get seg fault.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out. Really, many thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain that "return j+ind(a,5,3)". What does the + sign do here?

Comment: Oh, I got it. Don't bother man. Thank you so much for helping out. Have a nice day.